# How to eliminate theta here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck while solving for locus of a point, how to eliminate theta in this type of case:
$$\frac{-h}{a\sin\theta} = \frac{(b^2+a^2)\tan^2\theta}{b^2+a^2\sin^2\theta}$$ and $$\frac{-k}{b} = \frac{(b^2+a^2)\tan^2\theta}{b^2+a^2\sin^2\theta}$$ 
? Any tips please.

Answer (score 2):

Take the ratio of the two equations, which reduces the right side to $1$, and solve for $\sin \theta$.  Render $\tan^2 \theta=(\sin^2 \theta)/(1-\sin^2 \theta)$ in either of the original equations and proceed from there.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$  \tan^2x = {\sin^2 x\over 1- \sin^2 x}$$